# Repairing resistors

Tags: resistors, repair

I'm attempting to repair a resistor that was physically damaged by a heavy object. The part is a Yageo CFR-25JB-52-10K and the datasheet [may be found here](http://www.yageo.com/documents/recent/Leaded-R_CFR_2011.pdf). I've attempted to use [Loctite Epoxy Instant Mix 5 Minute](http://www.loctiteproducts.com/p/epxy_5min/overview/Loctite-Epoxy-Instant-Mix-5-Minute.htm) to repair but despite best attempts it's not conductive and when it seeps partly onto the carbon element it is increasing the resistance.

Looking on Wikipedia at Electrically conductive adhesive (I could only post two links as a new user) I see that the "The conductive component can be silver, copper or graphite". I wondered which of these three alternatives would be best for this application?

Edit - Reason I need to know is that I'm doing an Internship and have been given this task. My supervisor said it will be good practice for repairing more expensive components in the future like FPGAs he said can cost thousands of dollars.

Comment: Good question, I also have many of these expensive and difficult to source components awaiting repair.

Comment: Why repair a resistor instead of replacing? Do you want to learn or just get done with your goal?

Comment: These are [11c at DigiKey](http://www.digikey.com.au/product-detail/en/CFR-25JB-52-10K/10KQBK-ND/338). I fail to see the point.

Comment: This sounds like a military-style prank.  (1) Break a 1/4W resistor on an old board.  (2) Give a green guy some epoxy and tell him to repair it.

Comment: @PeterJ I suspect the humor in your comment might be wasted on some readers :-)

Comment: @Vikram I hope this question is a joke, and not serious.

Comment: Get yourself a new resistor, solder it in place, and tell your superior that loctite is no good for this job, you used CrackVanish (tm) instead. If you promise to make a foto of his face I'll send you the resistor. You'll have to make a bottle of CrackVanish yourself.

Comment: So is anyone going to explain to OP why you can't actually use epoxy to repair a carbon-film resistor? I'd write an answer, but I don't have time.

Comment: Well, some resistors indeed can be repaired, but not an FPGA - your supervisor is either incompetent or just ironic (I'd vote for the latter). It's like giving a person a bucket and sending him to the other building to get some vacuum.

Comment: Repairs like this are off-topic.

Comment: repair an fpga? wait, what?

Comment: Yup, sounds like a snipe hunt or being asked to go fetch a #5 skyhook.

Comment: Use the correct tool for the job! http://www.eetimes.com//electronics-blogs/other/4405831/Smoke-re-concentrator-refurbishes-blown-electronic-components?cid=NL_ProgrammableLogic&Ecosystem=programmable-logic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your interpretation of the request is a little off.

It's quite possible that "repair a resistor" and "replace a resistor" are analogous in your supervisor's mind. He/she could also be testing your common sense and judgement skills.

Removing and replacing damaged components is indeed good practice for anyone who needs to be efficient at troubleshooting. Also, I don't think IPC takes kindly on attempting to repair components in the manner you're describing. There's certainly no way you'll ever be able to repair an FPGA with glue, but you'll most likely need some skill in removing and replacing FPGAs...

Just replace the resistor with a new one and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple - Use any non-conductive glue you like. Then solder on the other side of the board a new replacement resistor.

Gives the appearance of working, doing what has been asked and should work ... yes it's cheating... but then if anyone asks you to glue 1/4 watt resistors together they are joking.... I hope...

Comment: I was never asked for a "Long Weight". but I did have a plan.. :-)